# Using .htaccess DirectoryIndex prevents from loading assets

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, web

So I have a bit of a problem. I've just uploaded my website files on a hostgator shared hosting server. I need to configure the .htaccess file in the so that the index directory is /me/web/app.php. I've written a simple

```
DirectoryIndex /me/web/app.php
```

and it redirects correctly, except that none of the assets are loaded. No css, images, etc. Whereas, when I load directly http://my-site.com/me/web/app.php, it works fine.

I guess my question is, what's going on here?

This is symfony 3 project, by the way. In case that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using Symfony 3.3 and my site also hosted on shared hosting.this .htaccess is working for me.

first clear cache, then try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This worked for me with Symfony 4 (I replaced "web" with "public").